# Burned magsafe dc in board ports: Replace, even if working?

Tags: macbook-pro, power, repair, magsafe

I have noticed that two of the pin plugs on my magsafe dc in board, the ones, which are for power are blacked. As far as I know, this is due to moisture.

Right now everything is working fine, however would it make sense to change the in board? Can the in board damage the magsafe or something else because of the condition it is in? Can I assume, that it will fail soon or is very likely to fail completely?

I ran diagnostics and it came back with 0 issues. However, I would rather fix it, than be surprised by it stopping to work at the worse moment.

Also should I only change the DC in board, or rather the i/o board? On some images it looks like, the DC in board is part of the i/o board.

This is what my dc in board looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifics will depend on your model, but in general it is quite difficult process for inexperienced person.

It consist of 20+ steps and without experience a lot can go wrong.

So the choice is yours, leave it as as and hope for the best or do it.

Here is an example of the process involved.

https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Unibody+Model+A1342+MagSafe+Board+Replacement/1676